# How many missing values in a dataset can Xgboost handle?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, missing-data, boosting, threshold

I have a dataset with a lot of missing values in the columns. I dropped all columns containing more than 70% of missing values.

I'm considering using Xgboost for my prediction because it can handle missing values in the training phase.

However the question is how many missing values can be in a column/row until the prediction with Xgboost is inaccurate?

Is there a rule of thumb or is this threshold specific to the characteristics of the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. In the worst case scenario, when all the values for a feature are missing, XGBoost will simply ignore the feature as it will be completely uninformative. I do not see much harm in keeping the features in. If you want, you can evaluate in cross-validation whether removing features with N% missing values improves the generalization of the model or not, treating N as just another hyperparameter to tune.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, while setting up your XGBoost, you can make use of the parameter called "missing" inside the xgboost as follows below:
Let's say you decide to fill up this missing values inside your dataset with (-99999) then parameter missing = -99999 and on the other hand if you decide not to fill up the missing values inside you dataset then set this missing parameter as missing = np.nan. You can see example below:

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_train, label=y_train, missing= -99999.0, enable_categorical=True)

dval = xgb.DMatrix(data=X_val, label=y_val, missing= -99999.0, enable_categorical=True)

dtest = xgb.DMatrix(data=comp_test, missing= -99999.0, enable_categorical=True)

model = xgb.train(params_xgb, dtrain,\
                       evals=[(dtrain,'train'),(dval,'val')],\
                       verbose_eval=100,
                       early_stopping_rounds=100,
                       num_boost_round=10000)
```